# Nested Button + Position on Screen

Tags: css, button, html, nested

Is there any nice clean way to put nesteded button elements of a div in center with style set to "table" ?

Ideally I do not want to contain the buttons within an additional div.

```
    <div class="the-tabs">
    <button class="tool-button dark_mini"><img src="Tools-icon.png"></button>
    <button class="help-button dark_mini"><img src="Info-icon.png"></button>
    <button class="save-button dark_mini"><img src="Zoom-in-icon.png"></button>
    <button class="save-button dark_mini"><img src="Save-icon.png"></button>

                <div id="the_preview" style="width:<?php echo $third_w;?>px;height:<?php echo $third_h;?>px;"> 
                    <div id="loading"><img src="images/loading.gif"><br/>Loading .... </div>

                    <img  src="<?php echo $the_img;?>" width=" <?php echo $width_new;?>px" height=" <?php echo $height_new;?>px" id="preview" class="preview_color"/>
                </div>
</div>
```

Comment: it would help if you provided some HTML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not 100% sure what you mean but here goes...

```
.the-tabs {
   text-align: center;
}
```

That will centre the buttons within the parent div. Is that what you mean?

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/F8tPC/)

Comment: Sorry yes I wrote it a little fast and seem to have missed out a few key points: div.the-tabs is set to display:table;

Comment: Thanks that worked. And funnily I had that inplace but forget I had buttons already set to float left. Cheers for the help